# Making the button changed to disabled while calc is running - in Dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a Dash app with a button which triggers a calculation.

The calculation itself takes about 20-30 seconds and I would like the button to change state to disabled and a spinner while it's calculating.

I've tried to use the following approach with a 'trigger' div which stores the state of calculation, but because of the multiple callback restriction in Dash I haven't been able to turn it back on when it finishes calculating.

I really cannot think of a way to get this to work with the 1-callback output restriction.

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button(id='submit-button-state-go-run-query',disabled=False),
    html.Div(id='graph'),
    html.Div(id='trigger',children=0, style=dict(display='none'))
])


###ENABLE-DISABLE THE BUTTON
@app.callback(
    Output('trigger','children'),
    Input('submit-button-state-go-run-query', 'n_clicks'),
             )
def disbutton(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks > 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
######################


###ENABLE-DISABLE THE BUTTON
@app.callback(
    Output('submit-button-state-go-run-query', 'disabled'),
    [Input('submit-button-state-go-run-query', 'n_clicks'),
     Input('trigger', 'children')])
def trigger_function(n_clicks, trigger):
    context = dash.callback_context.triggered[0]['prop_id'].split('.')[0]
    context_value = dash.callback_context.triggered[0]['value']
    if context == 'submit-button-state-go-run-query':
        if n_clicks > 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
######################


###MAIN FUNCTION
@app.callback(
    Output('graph','children'),
     #Output('trigger','children'), #tried getting the trigger div value to change when calc finished - but ran into 1-output restriction
    [Input('button','n_clicks')])
def update_element(n_clicks):
    #20-SECOND CALCULATION HERE
    return fig0 #, 1
```

UPDATE: tried implementing a global variable which holds the calculation state, but could only get the spinner to work - the state still does not change to disabled

```
computing = [False]

#CALLBACKS FOR QUERY
@app.callback(
    Output('graph0', 'figure'),

    Output("submit-button-state-go-run-query",'disabled'),
    Output("spinner",'children'),

    Input('submit-button-state-go-run-query', 'n_clicks'),
    State('EVENT_ID_state', 'value'), #
    State('MASTER_TICKER_STR_state', 'value'),
    State("full-input-boxes", "children"),
             )
def display_value0(n_clicks,event_id,master_ticker_str, children):

    if computing[0] == True:
        ...
    else:
        computing[0] = True
        
        #LONG CALC HERE
        
        computing[0] = False
    return fig_pg_0, False, []
```

UPDATE 2:

Moved the 'disabled' callback into a separate one (removed it from the long calc func) - this now disables the button while calculating, but never switches it back on.

```
@app.callback([
    Output("submit-button-state-go-run-query",'disabled'),
    #Output("spinner",'children')
],
[Input('submit-button-state-go-run-query', 'n_clicks')]
              )
def updatefn(n_clicks):
    time.sleep(1)
    print("after sleep computing is: ", computing[0])
    if computing[0] == True:
        return [True] #,[dbc.Spinner(color="light",size='sm')]
    else:
        return [False] #, []
```

Comment: Where does the output of the calculation go? If you place that in a div somewhere, you could have that as an input for the button as well. If it's empty (the calc is running), then disable. If it's got a value, then enable.

Comment: it's a chart underneathe the 'go' button. I don't think that will work - because after the 1st iteration - the chart already has a value - so it won't be able to distinguish between calculating and completed. I've tried an app.long_callback but it hasn't worked - just keeps automatically triggering the calc over and over.